# Match graph image with other graphs images using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

i want to compare a graph image (black line in a white background) with other set of graphs and identity most similar graph with that pattern .
what is the best way to do that in C#? does we need neural networks for this? 
i think we can't apply pixel count or image size for matching this... want to match the graph pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1:Get [Line boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460995/c-sharp-finding-the-boundaries-of-an-image-not-the-size) in two image.

2:Compute their [histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926067/simple-histogram-generation-of-integer-data-in-c-sharp) of selected area.

3:use [Bhattacharyya coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance) to compare the histograms.